# Null value when i get element of JSON

Tags: java, json, api

I'm automating incidents-creation via REST API. While reading JSON elements I got null value, I have used the same logic to start Scan with Rapid7 and it works fine.

JSON [image: JSON OBJECT]

The server does return JSON with the right attributes. but getting the attributes by name return null. can someone spot what wrong here ? Thank you

//Read

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String lines = null;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(lines);
}
bufferedReader.close();
result = stringBuilder.toString();
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result); // this works fine I can see all JSON elements ( incident_number, Sys_id, state, ect )

if (method.equals("GET")) {
    String incident_state = json.get("state").toString();
    System.out.print(incident_state);
    incident.setState(Integer.parseInt(incident_state));
    System.out.print("\n ServiceNow : Successful GET, incident is retrieved" );
}
```

I used the same logic with Rapid7 and works perfectly fine

```
//Read
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String lines = null;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(lines);
}
bufferedReader.close();
result = stringBuilder.toString();

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result);


if(methodType == MethodType.Retrieve_Vulnerability_info) {
    String scan_vuln_title= json2.get("title").toString();
    String scan_vuln_severityScore = json2.get("severityScore").toString();
    String scan_vuln_publishe_date = json2.get("published").toString();
    String scan_vuln_descriptiob = json2.get("description").toString() + splunkdata.getNmap_results();
    splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setSeverityScore(scan_vuln_severityScore);
    splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setVulnerability_title(scan_vuln_title);
    splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setPublished_date(scan_vuln_publishe_date);
    splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setDescription(scan_vuln_descriptiob);
    System.out.print("\n Rapid7 : Successful GET,  vulnerabilities info of : "+ scan_vuln_title + " were retrieved" );

}
```

Json as string :

```
{
    "result": {
        "promoted_by": "",
        "parent": "",
        "caused_by": "",
        "watch_list": "",
        "upon_reject": "cancel",
        "sys_updated_on": "2019-05-17 14:01:56",
        "u_validation_contact": "",
        "approval_history": "",
        "skills": "",
        "number": "INC2090774",
        "proposed_by": "",
        "lessons_learned": "",
        "state": "2",
        "sys_created_by": "sa_security",
        "knowledge": "false",
        "order": "",
        "cmdb_ci": "",
        "u_supplier_reference": "",
        "impact": "2",
        "active": "true",
        "work_notes_list": "",
        "priority": "4",
        "sys_domain_path": "/",
        "u_impacted_services": "",
        "business_duration": "",
        "group_list": "",
        "u_phone_validating": "",
        "approval_set": "",
        "major_incident_state": "",
        "short_description": "test",
        "correlation_display": "",
        "work_start": "",
        "additional_assignee_list": "46cfdce9db7157046ada1ded0b961990,4cff106ddb7157046ada1ded0b961905,2cb1adc2db9d7b803111f2603996197f",
        "notify": "2",
        "sys_class_name": "incident",
}
}
```

Comment: can you post your json ?

Comment: JSON is added to the main question

Comment: Can you post the full JSON as a string in the post? The given image doesn't show `incident_number` as a part of the json

Comment: updated - I also have the same issue with GET POST, check my main question

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing what your JSON structure looks like as you try to get the field? It could be you need to go one level deeper, since the provided image structure has "result" as the top level field; if it has that level, you may need to `get("result")` and then `get("FIELDNAMEHERE")`

Comment: JSON as String is added - Thanks, I have tried it I couldn't see why. I have used the same logic with another tool and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I have to go one step deeper, then retrieve result.
 Thanks to Austin Schafter for the suggestion.

```
  bufferedReader.close();
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result);
                JSONObject JsonResults = (JSONObject) json.get("result"); // here where the change needed 
 if (method.equals("GET"))
                {
                    String incident_state = JsonResults.get("state").toString(); // then use JSON which store results to retrieve other JSON elements by using name
                    System.out.print(incident_state);
                    incident.setState(Integer.parseInt(incident_state));
                    System.out.print("\n ServiceNow : Successful GET, incident is retrieved" );
                }
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer so others know the problem is solved.